# Invalid API key error when new IP address is added

Tags: google-places-api

We are trying to add a new IP address to our API key used with Google Places API. Existing IPs that we have associated with this key work. However, addition or changing an IP address from our original list of IP addresses is causing the Google Places API call to fail with the following error message:

```js
{
    "error_message": "The provided API key is invalid.",
    "html_attributions": [],
    "results": ,
    "status": "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

What should we be doing to resolve this? Is there any additional setting/configuration that needs to be done in the Google Places API account?

Answer (score 0):

use **

> Browser API

** key instead of server api key.. i too had same problem.